# Replace the content inside a DIV

Tags: php, html, regex, markup

I have a `div` called

```
 <div id="form">Content</div>
```

and I want to replace the content of the `div` with new content using `Preg_replace`.
what Regex should be used.?

Comment: It's described million times. Don't use Regex to work with HTML. Use DOMDocument or some other HTML parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to get contents of div class in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446766/regular-expression-to-get-contents-of-div-class-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

[You shouldn't be using a regex at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/196838). HTML can come in many forms, and you would need to take all of them in account. What if the id/class doesn't come in the place you expect? The regex would have to be really complex to get you reasonable results.

Instead, you should use a DOM parser - or a really cool tool I recently stumbled across, [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). With it, you can access your document in PHP almost exactly as you would with [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: -1 Dated joke pages don't make good explanation links. (You should read the title at least and past the non-answers somewhen, btw). We certainly have something more reasonable on SO.

Comment: @mario: I agree that the link is old and tongue-in-cheek, but this is an issue that does not age. I did try to look for a more serious answer but it's pretty difficult because SO doesn't have a "sort by best answer score" search. If you find one feel free to change it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in your case:

```
$html = '<div id="content">Content</div>';
$html = preg_replace('/(<\s*div[^>]*>)[^<]*(<\s*\/div\s*>)/', '$1New Content$2', $html); 
echo $html; // <div id="content">New Content</div>
```

However note that since HTML is not a regular language it is impossible to handle all cases. The simple regex I provided will produce bad output in the following example:

```
<div class=">">Content</div>
```